# YUI3 Promises not returning a value to .then()

Tags: yui, promise, yui3

I've been working recently developing some app using YUI3 Framework and I have problem with promises. I get no value in `.then()` function. Basically, `.then()` is not running. Why is this happening?

```
YUI().use('app', 'promise', 'io', function (Y) {
  var promise = Y.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    Y.io('js/template/app.html', {
      on : {
        success : function(_, v) { resolve(v.response); },
        failure : reject
      }
    });
  });

  promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

I'll appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Try removing the `sync` flag from your .io call. Also, I'm assuming you're saying that `"success"` is logged with nothing following it, right?

Comment: Nothing has changed. In on.success callback I get values I need, but I'm not able to get them later in the `.then()` code.

Comment: I never used YUI before, but I wrote a sample promisification for its XHR using its I/O with a bit more generic approach (merging the properties). Doing this, I can't seem to reproduce the error you mention, does this code help you? http://jsfiddle.net/K4SX6/ if it solves your problem - let me know and I'll formulate an answer, if it doesn't - let me know where it fails.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum 's points are both correct. I'd just add that: a) always use `new Y.Promise` and b) there's `gallery-io-utils` which creates a bunch of IO functions that return promises http://juandopazo.github.io/yui3-io-utils/. Benjamin you should go ahead and write an answer if you want.

Comment: @juandopazo if it's between you and me, it seems like you are the much more experienced one with YUI :) An answer form you will be much more authoritative and probably a lot more clear and concise. For example, I had no idea `gallery-io-utils` exists and it seems like that's what OP should be doing instead of re-promisifying every last bit of ajax (looking at the source, it looks very similar to how I manually did it).

Comment: @sunpietro, `app.cache[templateFilePath] = _.template(xhr.response)` or `app.cache[templateFilePath] = xhr.response`? You do both, first in the `success` hanldler, then in the `then` handler. The latter will override the former, which might be your problem.

Comment: @juandopazo - thank you for the reply, but it still doesn't work. I've re-edited the promise's piece of code above and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @sunpietro you're still not using `new` before `Y.Promise`, check out your console and my jsfiddle example...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum still not working. Here's my JSFiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/Paju2/

Comment: @sunpietro please create a valid self contained fiddle, that makes a call to the echo JSON service like mine, obviously it won't enter the `.then` when called on a non-existing file.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, sorry for bad example. Here's updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/Paju2/3/

Comment: @sunpietro querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, not an element, use `querySelector` instead... please make a minimal effort - I'm not enjoying debugging your unrelated code for you.  http://jsfiddle.net/477ZG/

Comment: Following juandopazo's recommendation to use `gallery-io-utils` I got **[a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DzL4b/)** working. I'm not sure it answers the question but may be a good basis for something. I have to say I find the YUI's lazy-loading syntax very unnatural but guess I would grow to like it if I had to.

Comment: It looked like the issue with Firefox browser itself. When I tested it with Google Chrome it started working. So, yes it is solved.